# Running a command or script in terminal from anywhere by adding it to the PATH, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: linux, macos, terminal

On osx/linux I want to be able to run a command on the terminal from anywhere which links to a certain program.

ie I want to be able to run:

`alloy`

that runs:

`/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/alloy/bin/alloy`

UPDATE:
Guess adding to .bashrc is the best way?

tried running: export

`PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/alloy/bin"`

and also:

`export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/alloy/bin/alloy"`

Then I started a new terminal window but the alloy command doesnt work. Am I missing something?

Comment: whats the default one in osx?
And in linux bash

Comment: Type `echo $SHELL` to find out.

Comment: Bash by looks of things. Seems like I should add to my .bashrc? I've added to my question what I've tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/alloy/bin in [your PATH](http://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/cs348/unix_path.html), or you can [create an alias](http://ss64.com/bash/alias.html) for alloy.

Comment: Just updated my question and tried adding it to my path via bashrc